# Which preposition is correct for the answer?

Tags: prepositions

> "Which is your English teacher"
> "The young lady ___ red over there."

> A: with
> B: in
> C: on
> D: for

The correct answer has been given as "with". I am very confused.

Comment: What do you think is the correct answer, and why?  If we just give you the answer, it is not going to help other English learners, and it would be like doing your homework for you.

Comment: You can't do homework on this site I am afraid. Edit your question to explain why you have doubts on what the right answer should be. But since you are new and have no way of knowing, I really think the downvote is harsh.

Answer (score 1):

> The young lady **in** red over there.

It means she is wearing a red outfit (perhaps, it's a red dress).

There is a quite popular song called "Lady in red" by Chris De Burgh, it goes like

> **The lady in red** is dancing with me, cheek to cheek...

Comment: Thank you. the right answer provided is "with", I feel very confused.

Comment: @gavinliu please update your question with this detail so people know what made you ask. Ideally, you also should have mentioned which option you think is correct

Comment: I can see *"lady with red hair"* would work, but hair wasn't mentioned there

Comment: I'd agree with you. I've always assumed that "[person] in [colour]" came originally from "[person] dressed in [colour]" and the verb was dropped.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think "in" is the right answer. The young lady in red over there.